# Excel Auto Sort then Summarize bulk data?

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I am want to be able to take "bulk" material lists and have them automatically summarized to "sum" like-with-like items.

For example, would there be an efficient way to accomplish the following?

Is there an efficient way to get from: 
[image]

To

[image]

I currently select all of the data from the first photo and do a SORT in the following order by the following:

1) Species 
2) Size (W) 
3) Size (H) 
4) Length
5) PCS

Then I select the "Sort anything that looks like a number, as a number" option. . .

But after I do that sort, I have to manually calculate the total quantity of "like" items in order to fully summarize my list to end up with how the second photo looks like. . .

Is there something that can automatically summarize the data from Photo 1 to make it look exactly like Photo 2?

Your help will make my life a LOT easier! Thank you for your time!

[image]

Comment: So what is your criteria here, if species matches and length matches nad size matches, then you can sum them together?

Comment: Yes - If the following items match:   Size (W), Size (H), Length, and Species - then I would like the list to automatically sum those items up.  Is that something you can help guide me in accomplishing?

Comment: Yes, I wrote a solution weeks ago but I never heard back from you :). I can see if I still have it tomorrow.

Comment: Great - thank you so much - that would be extremely helpful and greatly appreciated!

Comment: Good morning dwirony - I just wanted to follow up with you on this and ask again for your help.  This is something I've been trying to find a solution to for a long time so I just wanted to reach out and ask you again for your help on this - you would be helping me in such a huge way - thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

What this does is starting in row 2, checks all the other rows for a match based on Size (W), Size (H), Length and Species. If those all match, then PCS and Order are summed together and one of the rows are deleted.

```
Sub Consolidate()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 8 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 8 Step -1
            If i <> j Then
                If Cells(i, 6).Value = Cells(j, 6).Value And _
                   Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(j, 8).Value And _
                   Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(j, 9).Value And _
                   Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(j, 10).Value And _
                   Cells(i, 11).Value = Cells(j, 11).Value Then

                    Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value + Cells(j, 2).Value
                    Rows(j).Delete

                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: Thank you for the response dwirony - can you guide me in the right direct to know how to interpret the "meaning" of the formulas above?

Comment: Also, what are the steps i need to take to input this formula/coding?  Is it Visual Basic?

Comment: Ahh I'm sorry, I didn't realize you were looking for a formula. What you need is a macro - this is Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) - If you go to View -> Macros and name a macro, (say, "Test"), then hit create, copy and paste the above code over the `Sub` `End Sub` in the Test macro. Then when you run that, it will do what you're looking for.

Comment: So. . .i ran the test but my values did not sum up properly.  I should have noted also that the "sum" I'm needing is of the Column B values (PCS).  Also, in addition to counting if Size (W), Size (H), Length, and Species match I actually need the macro/VBA to summarize based on matching to an additional column which is not visible on my screenshots above which is column K which would be a "comments" column.  dwirony - any chance you could please try to rework the coding?

Comment: Btw - The concept of the test run was perfect - it attempted to summarize (even though the summarized values were incorrect) and it cleaned up everything by deleting the empty cells which was great.  If you are able to rework the code though so that the summed values would be correct per the additional information provided in my comment above that would be incredible - again, you would be making a significant impact in my productivity.  Thank you again dwirony!

Comment: @BryanM  Can you give me an example of what didn't sum correctly? I just posted the before/after with your test data, it looks correct to me. If there are additional fields you need to include that in your question and in your screenshot.

Comment: Ok - I believe that the error was on my part. . . .

Comment: For j = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If i <> j ThenIf Cells(i, 6).Value = Cells(j, 6).Value And _

Comment: Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(j, 8).Value And _

Comment: Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(j, 9).Value And _

Comment: Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(j, 10).Value Then

Comment: What is the coding above doing?

Comment: Starting in row 13 (`j` represents that), check if we're not checking against the same row (otherwise of course it would match), then if it's confirmed not the same row, check if Size, Length and Species match. If they match, the values are summed up and one of the two columns are deleted.

Comment: Ok, I apologize - I think that I have now finally cleaned up my question - I just inserted a NEW picture at the bottom of my original question showing the conditions of my current form.  Can you please try to modify your formula/code to work with the conditions in the new picture that I added to the bottom of my original picture?  Please forgive me - you are being of great help to me - I appreciate everything that you are doing to help!

Comment: Again - I'm needing to summarize PCS based if Size (W), Size (H), Length, Species and NOTE match

Comment: can you please format the coding you put together so that it works for the conditions in the NEW picture that I added to the bottom of my original post?  That's the final puzzle piece to my problem - thank you so much!

Comment: If you look at the new photo I posted at the bottom of my original question you can see that my reference cells are different than what you have formatted.  Can you please update your original coding so that it will reflect the specific cell references that are needed to work with the new photo that I added?

Comment: @BryanM Oh, the starting row you mean. Okay, I changed it from 2 to 8.

Comment: Ok - so the good news is that now the PCS column is summarizing perfectly but I have an existing formula that is in the ORDER column that is being messed with - is there a way to modify your formula/coding so that the formula in the ORDER column is not disturbed?

Comment: Edited to ignore the order column.

Comment: HUGE thank you for helping me out with this!! You're awesome - thank you again!

Comment: I am trying to use this same style of formula for another application.  In the formula you provided before. . .what does the first formula line "Dim i As Long" do? @dwirony

Comment: @BryanM `Dim i As Long` is a variable declaration, that's just saying "I want the letter i to ONLY represent a number in this macro".

Comment: Thank you. . .what does the second line mean "For i = 8 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row" @dwirony

Comment: @BryanM That's the start of a loop, saying start the value of `i` at 8 for the first iteration, incrementing by 1 all the way up to the number represented by `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` which is the last row of data contained in column A.

Comment: Also - what does the third line mean "For j = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 8 Step -1" @dwirony Thank you for your help in trying to better understand this

Comment: @BryanM That's also starting a loop but it's iterating from the bottom row to the top, `Step -1` means the number is decreasing instead of increasing (we don't say `Step 1` in our first loop because that's the value by default).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59759590/excel-auto-sort-and-auto-summarize @dwirony can you please go to that link - I went ahead and posted my new problem as another question.  Can you please help me out with that one?  It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760589/auto-sort-auto-summarize-excel@dwirony - sorry, I guess I formatted my question incorrectly and it was blocked.  Can you please take a look at the question in this link and help me out? Thank you for your help and your time.  Trying to figure this one out.